# glDrawElement crashes using GLSL shaders

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, opengl-3, opengl-4

I coded a simple program using GLSL which must display a simple textured Box. To do this I load an OBJ file called 'Box.mesh' and next I initialize VBOs for the vertex, normal, texture and index buffer.

Here's the Box.mesh file content :

```
o Cube
v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 -0.999999
v 0.999999 1.000000 1.000001
v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
vt 0.626059 0.265705
vt 0.626059 0.487398
vt 0.404365 0.487398
vt 0.626060 0.930786
vt 0.404365 0.930786
vt 0.404365 0.709091
vt 0.847752 0.487397
vt 0.847753 0.709091
vt 0.626059 0.709091
vt 0.182672 0.487397
vt 0.626059 0.044011
vt 0.404366 0.265704
vt 0.182671 0.709091
vt 0.404366 0.044011
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn -0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 1.000000 -0.000000 0.000001
vn -0.000000 -0.000000 1.000000
vn -1.000000 -0.000000 -0.000000
vn 0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
vn 1.000000 0.000000 -0.000000
usemtl BoxMtl
s off
f 1/1/1 2/2/1 3/3/1
f 5/4/2 8/5/2 7/6/2
f 1/7/3 5/8/3 6/9/3
f 2/2/4 6/9/4 3/3/4
f 3/3/5 7/6/5 4/10/5
f 5/11/6 1/1/6 4/12/6
f 4/12/1 1/1/1 3/3/1
f 6/9/2 5/4/2 7/6/2
f 2/2/7 1/7/7 6/9/7
f 6/9/4 7/6/4 3/3/4
f 7/6/5 8/13/5 4/10/5
f 8/14/6 5/11/6 4/12/6
```

And a piece of code of my program :

```
#define OFFSET_BUFFER(offset) ((char*)NULL + (offset))

[...]

//VBO Initialization

Basic::OBJReader objReader;
Basic::OBJImage objImg = objReader.Parse("Box.mesh");

GLuint handle[4];
glGenBuffers(1, handle);

std::vector<float> position = objImg.GetVertexPosition();

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, handle[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, position.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), &position[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

std::vector<float> normal = objImg.GetVertexNormal();

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, handle[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normal.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), &normal[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

std::vector<float> texture = objImg.GetVertexTexture();

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, handle[2]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texture.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), &texture[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

std::vector<unsigned int> faces = objImg.GetOBJFaceImageList().at(0).GetFaceData();

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, handle[3]);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, faces.size() * sizeof(GLuint), &faces[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

[...]

/*Main loop*/

while (isAlive == true)
{
    [...]

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, handle[0]);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, OFFSET_BUFFER(0));
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, handle[1]);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, OFFSET_BUFFER(0));
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, handle[2]);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, OFFSET_BUFFER(0));
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, handle[3]);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, OFFSET_BUFFER(0));
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    [...]
}
```

I checked the content and the size of all the buffers and they are correct. So I don't understand why I have a crash at the first call of glDrawElements. I'm really lost. Does anyone can help me, please? Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the votes to close on the grounds that it "lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem". Perhaps one of the close voters could leave a comment explaining what additional information they feel is necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `handle[3]` is your element array buffer, this is wrong prior to calling `glDrawElements (...)`:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, handle[3]);
```

It needs to be:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, handle[3]);
```

Presumably you have no element array buffer bound, and this instructs OpenGL that the final parameter in `glDrawElements (...)` is a pointer to client memory (instead of an offset into a buffer object's memory). GL will attempt to dereference a `NULL` pointer when it comes time to pull the vertex indices and then this happens.

Comment: Thank you very much. Effectively, it was not logical. Bye.

Comment: It is perfectly logical, you just have to know how `glDrawElements (...)` works ;)

Comment: I copied/pasted glBindBuffer with GL_ARRAY_BUFFER without take care of the flag. But I understand perfecly the working of glDrawElements. I will be more attentive the next time ;). Thanks again for your answer.